# Why we need float pointer or integer pointer to point float variable or integer variable respectively?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

What I know about pointer is, it is used to point to specific location (memory address), so why do we even need the same data type of pointer as that of the variable we are trying to point.
Suppose I create a variable of integer, then I have to create a pointer to integer to point it. So why can't I create a void pointer or float pointer to point the value stored in that integer variable!
Am I missing some concepts of pointers?

Comment: a `float` and an `integer` have different representations, hence the need for typeness w.r.t. to the pointer. You can have a void pointer but you'd have to cast the pointer to the correct pointer type prior to dereferencing. With a void pointer you have no idea what the value represents

Comment: How would you know what the pointer is pointing at unless you could tell from the type of the pointer? I suspect that you're missing the point of types in general.

Comment: Read up on dynamically typed languages versus statically typed. C and C++ belong to the latter category.

Comment: It is "only" to keep the type information. If you throw your type away ( void*) nobody knows what the pointer points to. You can see to which address it points to, but the compiler has no idea what kind of data you are pointing on.

Comment: C++ is a strongly typed language.  If you want a pointer to something you generally need a pointer of that type to point to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So why can't I create a void pointer [...] to point the value stored in that integer variable

You can do that, no problem:

```
int x = 10;
double y = 0.4;
void* v = &x;
v = &y;
```

But now imagine a function like this:

```
void print(void* value)
```

How would this function know what to do with the memory at the pointer location? Is it an integer? Or a floating point number? A `float` or a `double`? Maybe it's a huge `struct` or an array of values? You **must** know this to dereference the pointer (i.e. read the memory) correctly, so it only makes sense to have different pointer types for pointers to different types:

```
void print(int* value)
```

This function *knows* that the pointer points to an `int`, so it can happily dereference it to get an `int` value.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer type is also important when dealing with arrays, as arrays and pointers are interchangeable. When you increment a pointer (which is what indexing does), you need to know how big the type is (int, long, structure, class) in order to access the next item.

arr[5] == *(arr+5) but *5 what?*  This is determined by the type.

Comment: Pointers and arrays are not interchanable. Arrays may decay to pointers, as far as I know.

Comment: If you examine what's going on under the hood, arrays are implemented using pointer arithmetic. Anywhere you have an array, you can replace it with pointers, so in that respect they are interchangeable. Perhaps that's what you mean by "decay to pointers?"

Comment: @kbserson This is not true. Pointers and arrays behave differently. Just try this: `int arr[10]; int* ptr; cout << sizeof(arr) << endl; cout << sizeof(ptr) << endl;` The first output is (on my system) 40 and the second 8. This is just one case. There are more. If you pass an array to a function it decays to a pointer. This is what I call array decay. So after the passing to a function both would output 8. Or try to assign an array to an integer pointer. This also will not work.

Comment: Correct, their sizes won't be the same, but they can be used interchangeably.  If you have `int arr[10];` you can reference members by using an index `arr[5]=7;` or `*(arr+5)=7;`. In fact, since under the hood they are the same and you can write `*(5+arr)=7` you can also do `5[arr]=7;`

Comment: @kberson *under the hood they are the same* **No**, they are **not** "the same" under the hood.  `int a[10]` actually allocates space for 10 `int` values - the memory to store 10 `int` values *actually exists*.  `int *ptr` creates a pointer to an `int` value, and the value in that pointer may or may not be valid.  Creating a pointer does not create any space to store an actual object.  An array actually **is** a series of objects themselves.  There is a huge difference.

Comment: I think you are missing the point; I'm not talking about what get's allocated at declaration, I'm talking about the code that is generated in usage, after declaration. Once declared, anywhere you have code for an array, you can replace it with pointers, though it can get ugly when you add dimensions to the array.

Answer (score 2):

A small addition on Max Langhof's answer:

It is important to realise that in the end, variables are stored simply as a sequence of bits (binary digits), e.g. 01010101 00011101 11100010 11110000. How does your program know what this 'means'? It could be an integer (which is often 4 bytes on modern architectures), it could be a floating-point value. For the memory involved this makes no difference, but for your code the implications can be huge. Therefore, if you refer to this memory location (using a pointer), you will need to specify how the bytes there should be converted to decimal (or other) values.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer arithmetic is the main reason - if `p` points to an object of type `T`, then `p+1` points to the next object of that type.  If `p` points to a 4-byte `int`, then `p+1` points to the following 4-byte `int`.  If `p` points to a 128-byte `struct`, then `p+1` points to the following 128-byte struct.  If `p` points to a 2 Kbyte array of `double`, then `p+1` points to the next 2 Kbyte array of `double`, etc.

But it's also for the same reason we have different types in the first place - at the abstract machine level, we want to distinguish different types of data and operations that are allowed on that data.  A pointer to an `int` is different from a pointer to a `double` because an `int` is different from a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Although `int` and `float` are different types, there should be no difference between their pointers `int*` and `float*`. In **general**, this is the case. However, the binary representation is different between `int` and `float`. Therefore accessing an `int` with a `float*` pointer leads to garbage being read from the RAM.

Furthermore, what you have on your machine is not the general case, but hardware and implementation dependent.

**For example**: `float` and `int` variables are usually 32bit long. However, there are systems where the `int` has only 16bit. What happens now if you try to read a `float` from a `int*` pointer? (Or, even if both are 32bit, what happens if you try to read a `float` from a `char*`?)

Comment: `Therefore accessing an int with a float* pointer leads to garbage being read from the RAM.` Not only that, but it also violates the strict-aliasing-rule ==> Undefined behavior! In contrast char* may alias int*, so your last example is strictly speaking not a big deal as long you do not exeed memory

Comment: @Pi True. I didn't want to explain undefined behaviour, to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Memory accesses do not work without knowing what kind of data object you are dealing with.

Imagine some simple assignment:

```
int a, b=10;
float f;
a = b;  // same type => Just copy the integer
f = b;  // wrong type => Convert to float.
```

This works fine because the compiler knows that both variables are of a certain type and size and representation. If the types do not match, a proper conversion is applied.

Now the same with typed pointers:

```
int    a = 10;
float  f;
int   *pa;
float *pf;

f = a;   // Type conversion to float applied
*pa = a; // Just copy
*pf = a; // Type conversion
```

If you take away the knowledge about the memory location where the pointer points to, how would the compiler know if a conversion is required? 
Or if some integer propagation is needed or is an integer is truncated into a shorter type?

More problems are waiting around the corner if you want to use a pointer to address elements of an array. Pointer arithmetics won't fly without types.

Types are essential. For variables as well as for pointers.